# How to get an item from a void pointer to array when I know each element's size?

Tags: c, void-pointers

It comes when I want to write my own quicksort for educational purpose. This is what I got:

```
qsort(void* array, int count, int size, int(*compare)(const void*, const void*));
```

And I have size of each element in array, and pointer to the first element in array. How can I get each individual element in that array?

Comment: Do you know only the size, or do you know the type as well?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Like the built-in qsort, I know only the size of each element, not the type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If size was generated with the `sizeof` operator, it is a multiple of `sizeof(char)` (which is 1 by definition). So cast the `void*` into a `char*`, and move `size` "characters" at a time.

```
(((char*)array) + i*size)
```

Comment: The thing is, multiple data type could have the same size.

Comment: @ShaneHsu That's up to the compare function to sort out.

Comment: Actually `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so that requirement is moot.

Comment: @rodrigo, don't you mean that requirement is trivial? :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I gave best answer to you for being most explanatory.

Answer (score 4):

You would normally do the address arithmetic with `char *` pointers, e.g. to access element `i` of `array`:

```
char * array_ptr = (char *)array + i * size;
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy enough, cast it to `char*` and do pointer arithmetic:

```
char *carray = (char*)array;
char *pointer_to_n = carray + n * size;
```

BTW, some compilers such as GCC have an extension that allows to do pointer arithmetic to `void` pointers as if they were pointers to `char`, but that is non portable.