# How to edit a void type array

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers

How does one edit void pointers? Obviously, this is possible in C, because there are many standard library functions that do this.

I thought I'd implement a function swapping two array elements (I know there is a standard function for it, it's just an exercise), so ideally I'd want to do this:

```
void swap(void *arr, int a, int b, int elSize) {
    void arrEl = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = arrEl;
}
```

Of course, I can't dereference a void pointer, nor can I have a variable of type `void`, so I have to work around that somehow, but I discovered I don't know how to edit a void type array.
So how should I implement above pseudo-C?

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119680/how-to-get-an-item-from-a-void-pointer-to-array-when-i-know-each-elements-size), but I am not sure how to apply that and think seeing the correct version of above pseudo-C will make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Why you declared `arrEl` as `void`?

Comment: @haccks How do you mean? I know it is invalid C, but please read the last paragraph.

Comment: @haccks And what if I'd want to pass in a struct to this function? If this were a 'real' function I'd have to write another function like this, only with different types. I just wanted to learn about void pointers and then came across this.

Comment: You can pass struct (its address) to your function as `arr` is of `void *` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can't have a `void` array or `void` values. You can have a `void` pointer that points to an array of some type.

To use it you have to cast it to a non-void pointer, like e.g.

```
int value0 = ((int *) arr)[0];
```

And the simplest solution to not have to do this is to declare the pointer `arr` as a pointer to the type it actually is.

If you can't do that, then if you have the element size, you can declare temporary variable-length arrays to handle the swapping, like

```
char tmp[elSize];

memcpy(tmp, (char *) arr + elSize * a, elSize);
memcpy((char *) arr + elSize * a, (char *) arr + elSize * b, elSize);
memcpy((char *) arr + elSize * b, tmp, elSize);
```

The above swaps between the values at "index" `a` and `b`.

Comment: But say `elSize > sizeof(int)`, wouldn't I swap only part of a possibly large struct, thus corrupting the passed in array?

Comment: Thank you for the updates. One last question: is this temporary array trick considered 'standard'?

Comment: @11684 It's standard in C.

Comment: I'd use `char*` or `unsigned char*`, not `uint8_t*`. Presumably `elSize` is intended to be the size *in bytes*, which by definition is the size of a `char`. (It's possible to have `CHAR_BIT > 8`; in that case, `uint8_t` won't exist.)

Answer (score 1):

Joachim was a bit faster, but I'll add my answer anyway.

```
#include <string.h>

void swap(void *arr, size_t a, size_t b, size_t elSize) {
    char temp[elSize];

    memcpy(temp, (char*)arr+a*elSize, elSize);
    memcpy((char*)arr+a*elSize, (char*)arr+b*elSize, elSize);
    memcpy((char*)arr+b*elSize, temp, elSize);
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

int array[3] = {1,13,42};

char text[] = "This is text\n" ;

swap(text, 0, 2, 4);

printf("%s", text );

swap(array, 0, 2, sizeof array[0] );

printf("{%d %d %d}\n", array[0], array[1], array[2] );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between using `char` and `uint8_t` at all (except the first is obviously easier to type)?

Comment: There will probably be a difference on machines with CHAR_BIT unequal to 8. (these are rare today for general purpose machines, but some DSP's have 16 or 32 bit chars, IIRC) BTW: I don't expect these machines to have uint8_t defined. In any case: the smallest adressable unit of memory is char. (and therefore `sizeof (char)` is 1)

Answer (score 0):

By assigning `arr[a]` to `arrEl`, in fact you are dereferencing a `void` type pointer. And for this you must have to cast it before doing any operation to it. As;

```
int arrEl = ((int *)arr)[a];
```

or

```
int arrEl = *((int *)arr + a);
```

Comment: If you knew `int` was the right type, you wouldn't need to use `void*` in the first place, and you wouldn't need to pass `elSize`. `memcpy` is almost certainly the right solution.